# Scrollview in navigationview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I am implementing a side menu which has Listview and Expandable listview and a button at the bottom. If the listview or expandable listview is big then button a the bottom is not visible. Listview and Expandable listview are scrolling individually. I want to scroll everything at the whole.

Where can I put the scrollview. In the Drawyerlayout or navigationview?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="right">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/sidemenu_background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/student_name_layout"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stuent_name"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Student Name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/sidemenu_divider"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_menu_items"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:divider="@color/sidemenu_divider"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/sidemenu_divider" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ExpandableListView
                            android:id="@+id/dynamic_expandable_listview"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:childDivider="@color/sidemenu_divider"
                            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/sidemenu_divider" />

                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/logout_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/logout"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                android:text="@string/sign_out_text"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logout_icon"
                                android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />


                        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/sidemenu_divider" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please post your layout (xml) code?

Comment: please add code (xml)

Comment: Any suggestions?